# Match multiple outputs and print in a single file (sed,awk,for etc,)

Tags: linux, sed, awk, ksh

This kinda resembles a previous question of mine but it's rather complicated to explain. Anyways.

There is a file which contains different MAC addresses and a 2 Digit identifier for said device.  I am currently using something like this to get info out of that file:

`grep XX|cut -c45-56` *# XX Is the 2 digit pattern I mention above.*

So the above turns into something like:

```
grep XX|cut -c45-56 >> /tmp/file
grep : /proc/net/arp|sed 's|:||g' | grep file
```

Now XX (the 2 digit identifier) is right before field 45 on the line I'm currently grepping to get the MAC address off of (See first line).

So I would like for the final output to be something like::

```
XX MACADDRESS IPADDRESS
```

All of which are currently being grepped out of a file, should I do this inside a for loop and turn the outputs into variables? And if so, how would I go on about printing those with `awk`?

Any type of clear example will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is an example of the first file

```
> grep XX samplefile
0:0123:48: :3:/dev/ttyXX  :8:     :4P:XX:99:MACADDRRESSX
   :12222222:1322:46:XX1@231212:
```

As for the output file after the first grep, it's just a list of MAC Addresses. The final output, it would just be several lines of "XX MACADDRESS IP ADDRESS" I don't really care for headers or anything fancy at this time.

Comment: can you provide sample of your input file and your expected output.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Could you add the result of the first grep (it's not at all clear), an example of the second file, and what you'd like the final result to be?

Comment: I'm sorry. The result of the first grep is a MAC address that includes no semicolons. The file it's being dumped into it's just a list of MAC Addresses, hence I'm matching it to those in /proc/net/arp while eliminating the semicolons found in arp. I hope that clears things up a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
awk -vpat="XX" -f p.awk samplefile
```

where `p.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    while((getline < "/proc/net/arp")>0) {
        if (/:/) {
            gsub(/:/,"",$4)
            a[$4]=$1
        }
    }
}
$0 ~ pat {
    mac=substr($0,45,12)
    if (mac in a)
        print pat,mac,a[mac]
}
```

### Update

To avoid using `getline` you could try:

```
awk -vpat="XX" -f p2.awk /proc/net/arp samplefile
```

where `p2.awk` is

```
FNR==NR {
    if (/:/) {
        gsub(/:/,"",$4)
        a[$4]=$1
    }
    next
}
$0 ~ pat { 
    mac=substr($0,45,12)
    if (mac in a) 
        print pat,a[mac],mac
}
```

Comment: Read and make sure you fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're considering using getline.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the information. I will have a look at it.. Do you see any problems with using `getline` for this particular case?

Comment: Yes, if it fails (e.g. the file isn't readable or anything) it will return -1 and you will be stuck in an infinite loop. I haven't read the question (too much messy detail for me and I remember the OP from before not providing the necessary info to answer it) but I suspect using getline isn't necessary at all and you could just have an NR==FNR section.

Comment: I wouldn't say "to avoid using getline" because that makes it sound like using getline is the natural way to do it but has some issues so you need to code around it when in reality, the natural way to do it is just let awks normal file reading loop do what it does by default.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use python, ruby or any other more complete language? Python is probably already installed, and you won't need to learn any special magic to make it work.

It may be a bit longer, but you gain flexibility, testability, you'll be able to reuse part of the code easily etc.

For example, you could do in ruby:

```rb
def find_ip_in_arp(mac)
  # insert a colon every two digits, the output has the mac address with colons
  mac = mac.scan(/../).join(":") unless mac.include? ":"
  File.foreach("/proc/net/arp").grep(mac) do |line|
    return line.split.first  # the IP
  end
end

def find_mac_in_stream(ident, stream)
  stream.lines.grep(/^.{38}#{ident}.{4}(?<mac>.{12})/) do |line|
    return Regexp.last_match(:mac)
  end
end

def run
  to_match = ARGV.shift
  if mac = find_mac_in_stream(to_match, ARGF)
    if ip = find_ip_in_arp(mac)
      puts "#{to_match} #{mac} #{ip}"
      exit 0
    end
  end
  exit 1
end

run if $0 == __FILE__
```

so you can run this as `cat somefile | ruby thisscript.rb XX` or with the file as an arg: `ruby thisscript.rb XX somefile`.

You can do it shorter, by using more magic, or longer, being more explicit on any step. You hust have all the freedom in this world. Not so with AWK etc